# Local Notifications - asking for permission again after initially rejected

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

When an app launches for the first time, it will ask the user for permission to send local notifications.

If the user denies the permission at launch, how do we ask for permission again in the future?

For example, is there a way that on a button click, I can request permission again?

Here is my code to initially ask for permission at launch:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// are you running on iOS8?
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) 
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} 
else // iOS 7 or earlier
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
}
```

Comment: You can't force the system prompt.  All you can do is open Settings.app to your app's settings, and let the user change them.  Google for code to open Settings.app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for the first time you have disallowed local notification and on the second time use the blow mentioned code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *grantedSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

    if (grantedSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app-settings:"]];
    }
}
```

This will open your application settings where you can find the settings to enable/disable local notification and other settings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You never go to bed without learning something awesome!
Never knew you could link directly to settings!
Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can not request the system prompt again. You can detect a situation in which the access was denied and show an alert yourself or show the button that will open settings app to make the process of changing the setting easier for the user.